# iOS network quality

Tags: objective-c, ios, networking

Does anybody know if it is possible to analyze the (wifi) network quality on a iOS device? Like bars and speed.

I used the reachability project from apple, but i would like to have more information then the YES/NO result the reachability returns.

Comment: did you find a way to get more info than YES/NO on the network quality?

Comment: No. This was impossible at the time. Did not look into it since june-2011. That was before iOS 5. Maybe nowadays it it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, on the Mac there is the `CoreWLAN` framework, but there is no such framework (at least a public one) on iOS. It could be though that one can get low level and use some BSD calls, but I do not know that.